# Can you traverse Synology NAS using Python?

Tags: python, synology

Using the python request module and the official Synology documentation:

https://global.download.synology.com/download/Document/Software/DeveloperGuide/Package/FileStation/All/enu/Synology_File_Station_API_Guide.pdf

I have successfully retrieved API information, logged in, and requested for the File Station API. I've included my current code below:

```
import requests

if __name__ == '__main__':
    # Retrieve API Information
    response = requests.get("https://myds.com:port/webapi/query.cgi?api=SYNO.API.Info&version=1&method=query&query=SYNO.API.Auth,SYNO.FileStation.List")
    print(response.json())

    # login
    response = requests.get("https://myds.com:port/webapi/auth.cgi?api=SYNO.API.Auth&version=2&method=login&account="+str(user)+ 
        "&passwd="+str(password)+"&session=FileStation&format=sid")
    print(response.json())
    sid = (response.json()['data']['sid'])

    # request File Station API
    response = requests.get("https://myds.com:port/webapi/entry.cgi/?api=SYNO.FileStation.List&version=2&method=list_share&_sid="+sid)
    print(response.json())

    # logout
    requests.get("https://myds.com:port/webapi/auth.cgi?api=SYNO.API.Auth&version=6&method=logout&session=FileStation")
```

Doing this I can view the folders in the NAS, and looking at the Synology documentation I can download a specified folder or file within the drive with SYNO.FileStation.Download.

What I am wondering is there a way to use python to traverse subfolders within the drive and only download certain files (say based off of filename). I can't just download the main folder and then traverse it on my local machine (for example using the python OS module and the os.listdir() method) because it is extremely large so I need to do it through the APIs.

Comment: The API documentation explains how to enumerate (not download) directories and files. If you tried that, how did it not work for you?

Comment: @RogerLipscombe from my understanding of the documentation I would use the API: ```GET /webapi/entry.cgi?api=SYNO.FileStation.Download&version=2&method=download& path=%5B%22%2Ftest%2FITEMA_20445972-0.mp3%22%5D&mode=%22open%22 ``` to download a file at the specified path (or provide multiple paths) but I'm looking to download around 100 different files that are located in different subfolders

Comment: I see SYNO.FileStation.List, which you should be able to use to list the contents of each directory. Once you've found the files you want, _then_ you use SYNO.FileStation.Download

Comment: @RogerLipscombe would I not still have to manually hardcode the paths though? In my specific case there is one main folder and within that folder there are numerous other folders and within those subfolders there can be more folders that eventually contain a bunch of files. Sorry if that doesn't make sense it's hard to explain

Comment: No. Write a recursive function that uses SYNO.FileStation.List. It starts with the root, and recursively calls itself for each directory it finds. If, while doing that, it finds a file that matches your search pattern, it can download it.

Comment: @RogerLipscombe oh okay I understand what you saying. I will try that, thank you I really appreciate it